# How can I pass a primitive int to my AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

What I want it's to pass one `int` variable to my `AsyncTask`.

```
int position = 5;
```

And I declared my AsyncTask like this:

```
class proveAsync extends AsyncTask<int, Integer, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(int... position) {
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

But I got an error that it's the following:

> Type argument cannot be of primitive type

I just could pass an `int[]` and `Integer` variables but never an `int` variable and I execute my `AsyncTask` like this:

```
new proveAsync().execute(position);
```

Is there something that I could do to pass only this `position`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass your parameter as `Integer`

```
class proveAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... position) {
        int post = position[0].intValue();
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

while executing do this

```
new proveAsync().execute(new Integer(position));
```

You can get the int value in `AsyncTask` as using `intValue()`

Comment: Why you have to make reference to position like if it is an array? `position[0]`

Comment: because `...` means it can take any number of parameters and they are passed like an array. If you pass only one parameter get the first value.

Comment: Because the `...` indicates that it is an array. It means that the calling function (in this case, filtering down to execute(...)) can have one or more Integers given to it. You could have `.execute(1);` or `.execute(1, 2, 3)` or `.execute(intArray)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! You help me a lot ;)

Comment: I should probably mention that one or more is false. In my explanation. You can also give no input `.execute();`. In which case, the code in the sample above would crash with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can prevent that with some simple logic checking though as the first line of your `doInBackground`

Answer (score 5):

Use it like this.

```
class proveAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int position = params[0];
    ...
```

Pass position in an array. e.g:

```
Integer[] asyncArray = new Integer[1];
asyncArray[0] = position;
new proveAsync().execute(asyncArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping show this process in a different perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use constructor of AsyncTask .

```
class proveAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
int position;
     public proveAsync(int pos){
      position = pos;
     }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
    }

    .
    .
```

then use it like:

```
new proveAsync(position).execute();
```

and you can pass anything as of requirement without changing return type and arguments in this way..

Comment: What it is more efficient? To pass it with a constructor or to pass as a parameter?

Comment: The intended functionality of the AsyncTask is bypassed when done like this. Although the function of the code is performed how you want it to, it looks dirty. In my opinion at least.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Knossos!

Comment: and what if you want to pass it a Context.

Comment: and i have mentioned in first line that 

"You can also use constructor of AsyncTask "

i didn't said that it is the only way.

Comment: @sourabhbans: That is a different use-case though. No-one is saying that using the constructor is wrong in all cases. If you have two distinct pieces of data then the constructor is necessary. The way the AsyncTask is built is that you can pass it initialization variables in the constructor (in your case, a Context) and variables to worked on are passed as an execute argument.